# Install and configure TLS/SSL certificate on ejabberd server for Windows 10 OS

Tags: windows, ssl, xmpp, ejabberd

Being novice to Ejabberd, I have installed ejabberd-18.12.1 server on Windows 10 OS and able to run successfully on localhost. Can open the admin screen and even add users through the admin screen.I'm having trouble in connecting the XMPP clients such as Gajim or Pidgin installed on same machine to the ejabberd server(localhost). It seems to me as an issue of TLS/SSL security certificates. Can someone please help me in guiding the installation and configuring the certificates on Windows 10 OS for Ejabberd server from beginning.

Comment: Hi, I've installed ejabberd 19.02, and I see in the configuration file ejabberd.yml that it includes and uses a self-signed certificate. It's possible that those clients warn the user about that: the certificate is self-signed. It isn't possible to help more, because you don't tell if the ejabberd log files contain some error message, or what error messages provide the clients, or what do they complain.

Comment: Thanks. I installed ejabberd 19.0.2 and it worked for me.